# Problem installing Small Basic

Tags: installation

I am using Windows Vista Home Premium Service Pack 2. Dot Net Framework 4.0 is installed in my computer. But when I am trying to install Microsoft Small Basic, It is showing an error "This application requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" and installer exited. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could try installing [Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&displaylang=en) and its [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en).

I would expect programs to be happy with a later version but maybe Small Basic requires something that is only in that version or somebody forgot to add the "or later" bit when specifying that Small Basic needed version 3.5 or later. Anyway, at least the installer is giving you a clue about why it is failing...

Comment: Your answer is correct, but versions of .net don't work like this. 4.0 does not necessarily include 3.5 or 3.0 or 2.0 or 1.1! So every version needs to be separately installed, although 3.0 and 3.5 depend on 2.0

Comment: Quite. I have trouble with all the different versions. [It seems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/04/20/9557946.aspx) that the versions work as one would expect versions to work up to version 2 (apart from where they don't), and version 3.5 gets round it by installing versions 2.0 and 3.0 alongside itself. I have no idea what version 4 does, maybe from the problem above it has given up in disgust. I was trying to avoind an answer which just said "Well, install what it tells you then!"